# mottie tablesorter display max value of each columns when rows are filtered

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm wondering if there was an easy way to use mottie's jquery tablesorter to figure out the new max value of each columns when rows are dynamically filtered and display it right under the column heading as a cell.  The max value of each column changes as rows gets filtered.

Comment: Can you please share a demo of what you are describing. Modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/), and please indicate where which column and where in the heading you need the value. Thanks

Comment: Thank-you for you quick response Mottie.  I would like a sticky row, right under "Numeric" that has a cell which displays the Max value of all values in the "Numeric" column.  As rows are filtered, the Max value should change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/806/)):

```
var $t = $('table'),
    maxColumn = 1, // zero-based index of column number
    getMax = function () {
        var c = $t[0].config,
            col = c.$tbodies.find('tr:visible').map(function () {
                return parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(' + maxColumn + ')').text(), 10);
            }).get();
        c.$headers.eq(maxColumn).find('span').text( Math.max.apply(Math, col) );
    };
$t
    .on('filterEnd', function () {
        getMax();
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blackice',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        initialized: function () {
            getMax();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did I say you are AWESOME!  Well, you are.  Thanks so much.  Made my day.